# Why do I need add the folder when I get FileInputStream from a file?

Tags: android

I have read the article at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

The Code A works well, but the Code B doesn't work well, I must use the code `inputStream = new FileInputStream(mContext.getFilesDir()+"/hello_file");`

Must I add folder when I read the files stored internal storage ?

**Code A**

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

**Code B**

```
 InputStream inputStream = null;
   int size = 0;
   try {
                inputStream = new FileInputStream("hello_file");
                size=inputStream.available();
                Utility.LogError("Size Html: "+size );
            }catch (Exception e){
                Utility.LogError("Error: Input"+e.getMessage() );
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To get FileStreams use:**

[openFileInput(String name)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput(java.lang.String))

[openFileOutput(String name, int mode)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,%20int))

---

**Some Details:**

`openFileInput` `openFileOutput` are methods of `Context`.

In Code a you are using `openFileOutput`. If you check out [a src](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java).
You can see that `openFileOutput` does the following:

```
...
File f = makeFilename(getFilesDir(), name);
...
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f, append);
...
```

So the path used to generate the output stream is the same as the path you provided:

```
mContext.getFilesDir()+"/hello_file"
```

---

The mistake **In Short**:

Code A: will write to:   +"/hello_file"

Code B: Tries to read: "/hello_file"